# How can I redeclare stdout in same function

Tags: javascript

2I'm trying to use stdout
I want to use different command git and output the result.
But How can I redeclare a stdout ?

Thanks for your help :)

```
 public async test(){

 //some script

 const command = 'git rev-parse '+lastTag // lastTag is a label for a tag
 let out = "";
 const { stdout } = await this.exec(command)
 out = stdout.replace(/\n/g,'')
 console.log(out)

 const command2 = 'git rev-list --count HEAD ^'+out 
 let out2 = "";
 const { stdout } = await this.exec(command2) // error redeclare stdout
 out2 = stdout.replace(/\n/g,'')
 console.log(out2)

}
```

Comment: Re declare or re assign?? ,const can't be reassigned in the same scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. Don't use a constant
2. Break your code into smaller functions

For example:

```
 public async test(){

 //some script

 const command = 'git rev-parse '+lastTag // lastTag is a label for a tag
 let out = "";
 let { stdout } = await this.exec(command)
 out = stdout.replace(/\n/g,'')
 console.log(out)

 const command2 = 'git rev-list --count HEAD ^'+out 
 let out2 = "";
 { stdout } = await this.exec(command2)
 out2 = stdout.replace(/\n/g,'')
 console.log(out2)

}
```

or

```
async function runcommand(command) {
  let out = "";
  const { stdout } = await this.exec(command)
  out = stdout.replace(/\n/g,'')
  return out;
}

async function test(){

     const out = await funcommand('git rev-parse ' + lastTag);
     console.log(out)

     const out2 = await runcommand('git rev-list --count HEAD ^' + out);
     console.log(out2)

}
```